# ZF2 FormRow without View

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I am integrating ZF2 forms into a legacy PHP application, using just the components and not the MVC framework.

Building the form and elements is easy, and here's how I am rendering the form in my Form class:

```
    <?php
    public function render()
    {
        $this->prepare();

        $helper = new \Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form();
        $renderer = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
        $helpers = $renderer->getHelperPluginManager();
        $config = new \Zend\Form\View\HelperConfig();
        $config->configureServiceManager($helpers);
        $helper->setView($renderer);
        return $helper->render($this);
    }
    ?>
```

This works, but I want to be able to render each element in a FormRow.  There's plenty of code samples for doing this in a view, but I need to do this in my Form class.

Any suggestions?